# Select ticket ID if, customer with closed status exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have customers on my DB with too many tickets, and these tickets have too many statuses. I want a query that could pull the cutomer's ticket number, only if the ticket with status!='Closed'. Otherwise it should return null.

Your fast response is highly appreciated.

Edit: Here is my query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN custom_field_3 != 'Closed' THEN item_id ELSE NULL END AS ticketID 
FROM aims_items 
WHERE custom_field_22 =221226
```

It works now, and here is my solution:

SELECT
  CASE WHEN
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM aims_items
    WHERE custom_field_3 != 'Closed'
    AND custom_field_22 =221226
   )>0
  THEN 
   item_id
  ELSE 
   NULL
  END 
AS ticketID
 FROM aims_items
 WHERE 
 custom_field_3 != 'Closed'
  AND 
 custom_field_22 =221226
Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Have you tried to write this query?  If so, then post what you have tried. Also posting table structure, sample data would also be very helpful.

Comment: @hassan: And the problem with your query is?

Comment: i have updated the answer, can you please check it and see if it can help you

Comment: @hassan what is the issue with your query? Seems like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Without table structure it is not possible to evaluate what the issue is.  From your description a simple query like

```
SELECT item_id from aim_items WHERE custom_field_3 != 'Closed' AND custom_field_22 = 221226
```

Would suffice.  You can then count the number of rows returned to determine result.

If, however, you require null to be returned as a result, try the following :

```
SELECT (SELECT item_id from aim_items WHERE custom_field_3 != 'Closed' AND custom_field_22 = 221226) AS ticketID
```

The above encapsulates the basic select into a subquery, to provide a null result.

Comment: Hassan wants Null when condition is not satisfied. With all due respect, i would like to ask you that whether this query returns null when condition is not satisfied? I think this will fetch the ids of records that match condition. I make it pristine that it is not an argument but a question out of my curiosity.

Comment: yeah Bhavik, it should return null, or empty value if the condition is not satisfied

Comment: @Hassan I have expanded the answer for you.  Not sure what you are tying to do, perhaps it would be better if you place the question in context as I suspect there are better solutions to your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT IF(custom_field_3!='Closed',item_id,'') as ticketID FROM `aims_items`
```

Remember, i have not written the exact fields that you have in your table. This is just example to show you. Refer to below link for detailed information
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html